# iPhone - core data inspecting inside a NSSet attribute on a fetch

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a core data structure of Books and Bundles. A book can belong to one or more bundles, so, I have a many-to-many attribute in place between the two. On the book this attribute is called fromBundle.

I have my class for each entity. This class was written when instead a many-to-many I had just a to-many relationship... so, at that time, fromBundle was not a NSSet. My problem is this, I have to build a predicate that could look inside the fromBundle NSSet and see if the set contains the bundle I am looking for.

This is the code I had before the change.

```
Bundle *aBundle = [Bundle bundleComNumber:aNumber  inManagedObjectContext:context];


NSArray *all = nil;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];

// the problem is on the next line... as I see, the line is not looking inside the NSSet
// I may be wrong, but when I run this, it crashes and stops on the executeFetchRequest line
// saying **to-many key not allowed here**

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                     @"(fromBundle == %@)", aBundle];


[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Number", nil]];


NSSortDescriptor *sortByItem =  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ordem ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByItem];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];



NSError *error = nil;
all = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];  // it is crashing here saying **to-many key not allowed here**
[request release];

return all;
```

what am I missing?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a predicate like `@"%@ IN fromBundle"` instead?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  ThAnKs!!!!! I love this community!!!!